# Pandas - drop all rows with 0 in at least two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have some DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['apple1', 'apple2', 'apple3', 'apple4', 'orange1', 'orange2', 'orange3', 'orange4'], 
                   'A': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0], 
                  'B': [0.10, -0.15, 0.25, -0.55, 0.50, -0.51, 0.70, 0], 
                  'C': [0, 0, 0.25, -0.55, 0.50, -0.51, 0.70, 0.90],
                  'D': [0.10, -0.15, 0.25, 0, 0.50, -0.51, 0.70, 0.90]})
df
    name    A   B   C   D
0   apple1  0   0.10    0.00    0.10
1   apple2  0   -0.15   0.00    -0.15
2   apple3  0   0.25    0.25    0.25
3   apple4  0   -0.55   -0.55   0.00
4   orange1 0   0.50    0.50    0.50
5   orange2 0   -0.51   -0.51   -0.51
6   orange3 0   0.70    0.70    0.70
7   orange4 0   0.00    0.90    0.90
```

I'd like to **drop** all rows that have two or more zeros in columns `A,B,C,D`.

This DataFrame has other columns that have zeros; **I only want to check for zeros in columns `A,B,C,D`.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) to check if dataframe is equal to 0 and then take [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) on `axis=1` and return a boolean series by checking if the sum is greater than or equal to 2 ([`ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html)):

```
df[~df[['A','B','C','D']].eq(0).sum(1).ge(2)]
```

---

```
    name    A   B   C   D
2   apple3  0   0.25    0.25    0.25
4   orange1 0   0.50    0.50    0.50
5   orange2 0   -0.51   -0.51   -0.51
6   orange3 0   0.70    0.70    0.70
```

Comment: This works. Only comment would be to *remove* these rows: `df[~df[['A','B','C','D']].eq(0).sum(1).ge(2)]`

Comment: @BuffaloCollector ahh okay, yes :) Thank you I missed the part where they had to be dropped